# How do I upload datasets to a Google Cloud PostgreSQL Instance that other users can see?

Tags: database, sql, postgresql, google-cloud-platform

I have uploaded several datasets to my Google Cloud PostgreSQL instance on the default user account. But when I try to view those same datasets on my second user account, they're no longer there. It seems like the second account is connecting to another database. When I log in with the first account, I get the message "`u'Connected: postgres@datasets'`". When I log in with the second account, specifying the exact same database name (datasets), I get this message: "`u'Connected: user_2@datasets_1'`". It's adding the `_1` to the database name. Does anyone know why this is happening and how to stop it?

On a related note: once the first problem is resolved, I need to modify privileges on the second user account so that anyone using it cannot modify or delete any tables in the database. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out the answer. I had to add grant the ability to select to user_2. I did so by following the answer to this stack overflow question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13497352/error-permission-denied-for-relation-tablename-on-postgres-while-trying-a-selec

Specifically, here's the code I used:

```
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO user_2
```